# Related to django admin customization

Tags: python, django

In django let say I have three models

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

In django admin for adding a new book If I want to have 
Publisher field in the form also.How can I do it?
Really appreciate your any help.

Comment: You want to create a new publisher or associate a book with a publisher?

Comment: It would have one already, what is the exact issue you're having?

Comment: @ Shang Wang From django admin I want to manually  create a new book and associate a publisher with that.For that purpose in the form I want publisher field.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the publisher along with the author (not choose or create new publisher) then, you can modify your `Author` model to display both author name and publisher name in the Select field for Author.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + ' - ' + self.publisher.name
```

Comment: @ Muhammad Tahir From django admin I want to manually  create a new book and associate a publisher with that.For that purpose in the form I want publisher field.

Comment: Why don't you have a `ForeignKey` field with `Publisher` model in `Book`?

Comment: 'Author' has 'publisher' as foreign key.So its like 'Publisher' ==> 'Author' ==> 'Book'.Anyway  here also 'Book' is related to 'Publisher' indirectly.So I want to acess 'Publisher' field while adding a new 'Book' from admin.